# Problems running visual studio executables with mono

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mono

I'm trying to run with Mono executable files created by visual studio 2010.
Setting in VS 2010 are:
-c++ project
-cil pure

My final target is to compile Parsec benchmarks using visual studio 2010 and then run the executables with mono both in windows and linux.

By now I created a simple c++ project including only a printf.
The executable runs fair with mono under windows, while it gives me back many problems under linux

this is what i get:

```
** (thread.exe:1424): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /home/chezz/Scrivania/thread.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.FixedAddressValueTypeAttribute

** (thread.exe:1424): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /home/chezz/Scrivania/thread.exe mtoken: 0x0a00000d

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for <Module> ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.AppDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain'.
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00000] 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception innerException) [0x00000] 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00000] 
  at <Module>..cctor () [0x00000] 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any idea?
Thanks
Andrea

Comment: If you write C++ code, why do you insist on compiling to IL? And are you sure that Mono runs you program and not the .NET framework?

Comment: I was requested to do this kind of job for my thesis work, in order to support pthread in multiplatform compilation
 I also tested the executable with MoMA and it sent good feedback for windows

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the code that the Visual C++ compiler generates will use the MSVCRT if you call functions that are in the C Runtime (i.e. non-.NET, like `printf`). To be able to run on Mono on Linux as well, you should only use the .NET framework classes (for example `System.Console.WriteLine` for console output instead of `printf`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe reading [Mono-C++](http://www.mono-project.com/CPlusPlus) might help you with your issue. Look towards the bottom about C++ support and the problem with running C++ code.